# How to read output from a double click .jar file

Tags: java, cmd, jar

I have exported a Java program to a .jar file. When I run it from the cmd, it works fine and shows me the output. When I try to double-click it, it surely starts (because it asks me for an input), but then I can't understand if it keeps working because I can't see any output.
Any help?

Comment: The problem is that you operation system associates the file extension *jar* with the `javaw` executable which does not open a console which could display the output. Either configure you operation system to use `java` executable (instead of `javaw`) or change your program to use a logging framefork instead of `System.out.*`. This way you get your output in a logfile too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write the output to a file or keep calling it from a batch file. The content of this file should be like:

```
java -jar yourJar.jar
```

Then you can doubleclick the .bat file. Make sure your JAR contains a manifest that specifies the main class.